# How to avoid error "procedure too long" when having 333kb/7200 lines for bookmarks?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm using an Excel file to export different data into 2400 different bookmarks location in a Word document. The file is 333kb/7200 lines, and therefore getting the error "procedure too long".
I have this code as seen under here with 1 example (real file has ca. 2400 eksamples) which I need combined with a solution where I'm calling sub procedures or modules, but it's not working so good.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\eksempel på mappe\"
Dim wd As New Word.Application

Sub ExportButton()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    wd.Visible = True

    Dim eksempel1 As String

    eksempel1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a1").Value

    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "output.docx")
    Copy2word "eksempel1", eksempel1

    doc.Close

    wd.Quit
    'MsgBox "Created files in " & FilePath & "!"
End Sub

Sub Copy2word(BookMarkName As String, Text2Type As String)
    'copy each cell to relevant Word bookmark
    wd.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookMarkName
    wd.Selection.TypeText Text2Type
End Sub
```

Have been told that I could call the data for my bookmarks as seen hereunder, but it's not working.

My data in excel is in: B10 - B401, C10 - C401, D10 - D813, E10 - E813.

```vb
Dim Counter As Long
Dim eksempel As String
For Counter = 1 To 401 ' Eller, hvor langt ned din bogmærke liste er
eksempel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("b" & Counter).Value

Dim Counter As Long
Dim eksempel As String
For Counter = 1 To 401 ' Eller, hvor langt ned din bogmærke liste er
eksempel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("c" & Counter).Value

Dim Counter As Long
Dim eksempel As String
For Counter = 1 To 813 ' Eller, hvor langt ned din bogmærke liste er
eksempel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("d" & Counter).Value

Dim Counter As Long
Dim eksempel As String
For Counter = 1 To 813 ' Eller, hvor langt ned din bogmærke liste er
eksempel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("e" & Counter).Value
```

Comment: How you want to copy the data, just as it is? i.e.: B10, B11, B12, etc.. no space, no comma, nothing?

Comment: How are the bookmark names related to the Excel cell locations?

Comment: *Which* file is too long: " The file is 333kb/7200 lines"? The error you quote more likely refers to the code, not a Word or Excel file: "procedure too long"... Please be more specific with what you mean by "it's not working."  You need to provide enough information so that we can reliably reproduce what you're trying to do!

Comment: Hi, 
I need the data copy one by one, since each one is linked to a specific bookmark. @Cindy, The code i wrote is giving me the error when i activate it.

Comment: @FAB I need the data copy one by one, since each one is linked to a specific bookmark.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I need the data copy one by one, since each one is linked to a specific bookmark.

Comment: @NicolaiIbsen what do you mean by `each one` ? you only ever use one (`eksempel1`) in your code, so is kind of hard to guess what you mean.

Comment: You're not explaining well what it is you're trying to do.  Are you trying to copy your data to a table?  Your second example doesn't help that much.  Is all your data going to a single Word file?

Answer (score 0):

A [string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#string-data-type) variable should easily support quite a lot of text.

See if this helps:

```vb
Sub ExportButton()

Dim doc As Word.Document
wd.Visible = True

Dim arrData As Range: arrData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B10:E813")
Dim eksempel As String
Dim R As Long, C As Long

For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
    For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        eksempel = eksempel & arrData(R, C)
        If (C = 1 Or C = 2) And R = 392 Then Exit For
    Next R
Next C

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "output.docx")
Copy2word "eksempel1", eksempel1

doc.Close

wd.Quit
'MsgBox "Created files in " & FilePath & "!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Sub ExportButton()

Dim doc As Word.Document
wd.Visible = True

Dim arrData As Range: arrData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B10:E813")
Dim eksempel As String
Dim R As Long, C As Long

For C = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
    For R = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        eksempel = eksempel & arrData(R, C)
        If (C = 1 Or C = 2) And R = 392 Then Exit For
    Next R
Next C

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "output.docx")
Copy2word "eksempel1", eksempel1

doc.Close

wd.Quit
'MsgBox "Created files in " & FilePath & "!"

End Sub

Comment: @NicolaiIbsen comments are not really friendly for code.

Answer (score 0):

Best Guess:

```
Const FilePath As String = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\eksempel på mappe\"

Sub ExportButton()
    Dim wd As New Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim Counter As Long

    wd.Visible = True
    Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "output.docx")

    For Counter = 1 To 401
        CopyToWord doc, "eksempel" & Counter, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("b" & Counter).Value
    Next

    doc.Save
    doc.Close

    wd.Quit

End Sub

Sub CopyToWord(doc, bmk, txt)
    Dim rng
    Set rng = doc.Bookmarks(bmk).Range
    'next line will destroy the bookmark...
    rng.Text = txt
    doc.Bookmarks.Add bmk, rng '<< restore the bookmark
End Sub
```